# What is so "special" about a mirror ? To cause it to redirect/reflect electromagnetic radiation?

Tags: optics, photons, reflection

What is so "special" about a mirror ? To cause it to redirect/reflect electromagnetic radiation ?

Comment: This will probably help you.  I'm not gonna try to do better https://youtu.be/1n_otIs6z6E

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do metallic objects reflect radar?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/671181/why-do-metallic-objects-reflect-radar)